# Running with Bazel makes GetTempPath return C:\Windows\

Tags: c++, windows, bazel

I have a test that calls `GetTempPathW` and tries to create temp files in the returned dir. When I run the test directly, `GetTempPathW` returns `C:\Users\sgreens\AppData\Local\Temp\` and it passes. When I run it with `bazel test`, it returns `C:\Windows\` and the test is unable to create files there.

From the [documentation of GetTempPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The GetTempPath function checks for the existence of environment
>   variables in the following order and uses the first path found:
>
> 1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
> 2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
> 3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
> 4. The Windows directory.

In the cmd window I run bazel from:

```
C:\Users\sgreens\yeti\yeti>echo %TMP%
C:\Users\sgreens\AppData\Local\Temp

C:\Users\sgreens\yeti\yeti>echo %TEMP%
C:\Users\sgreens\AppData\Local\Temp

C:\Users\sgreens\yeti\yeti>echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\sgreens

C:\Users\sgreens\yeti\yeti>echo %WINDIR%
C:\WINDOWS
```

In the CROSSTOOL generated when I build:

```
  env_entry {
    key: "TMP"
    value: "C:\\Users\\sgreens\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
  }
  env_entry {
    key: "TEMP"
    value: "C:\\Users\\sgreens\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
  }
```

What is Bazel doing to cause `GetTempPath` to return `C:\Windows\`? How can I fix it?

Possibly related issue:
['$' sign in the output base make all tests failed on windows](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the test directly, you run it in your normal command environment. The test sees the same environment variables as you do, i.e. it uses the `TMP`/`TEMP` variables that you've printed.

When you run the test with `bazel test`, Bazel runs it in a trimmed-down environment, with as few environment variables defined as possible. Bazel does this to make the test as reproducible as possible: if the test depended on the client environment, then changing an environment variable may let it pass or make it fail, and we don't want such unpredictable behaviour.

This is a known issue, and I'm actively working on resolving it: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2870

A workaround for you is to use `--test_env=TMP`. This flag tells Bazel to copy your `TMP` value to the test's environment.